# How does Keras Evaluate/Handle Multilabel Sigmoid Problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

As I am working on tuning a model multilabel densely connected model, I am realizing that I don't understand how the model is being evaluated. My current model has 20 potential labels and ends with a sigmoid activation function and 20 nodes. As intended my model is properly displaying 20 different probabilities, range 0-1, for each item that it classifies. As I tune my model, I am simply using `model.evalute` from [tensorflow/keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate) to grab my testing accuracy.

But what is this accuracy telling me? Is it the average of true positives for each of the 20 labels for each classified item? Or is it using an "exact match" approach where a classified item is only correct if every label is properly predicted. On top of this, I am assuming that there is a some sort of base threshold for the probability that is true of false. I am not seeing anywhere in the documentation where this threshold is disclosed.

I ran an experiment and attempted to introspect the predicted outputs of my model. Using the code below (results being an array of predictions and y_test being the associated array of correct labels), I was unable to reproduce the accuracy that `evaluate` was giving me. For example, in a test run with 0.01% of my trainers, I had 14 samples with 20 labels a piece. The accuracy was 35.714%. I take this as either there were 5 of 14 samples that were correctly classified as exact matches, or there were 100 out of 280 individual labels classified correctly. However at thresholds of 0.50, 0.75, 0.90, and 0.99 I can't get either of those outcomes. So I am really not quite sure what is going on.

```
correct = []
incorrect = []
total = []
all_right = []
for result, label in zip(results, y_test):
    flag = False
    for r, l in zip(result, label):
        if l == 1:
            if r >= 0.50:
                correct.append(1)
            if r < 0.50:
                incorrect.append(1)
                flag = True
        if l == 0:
            if r >= 0.50:
                incorrect.append(1)
                flag = True
            if r < 0.50:
                correct.append(1)
        total.append(1)
    if not flag:
        all_right.append(1)
```

Here is my model if this is helpful:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=input_dim))
model.add(layers.Dropout(drop_weight))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(drop_weight))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001, rho=rho)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
```